# How to convert utf-8 codes in binary file to html codes in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

The HTML files I am dealing with are generally utf-8 but have some broken encodings and therefore can't be transformed to Unicode. My idea is to parse them as binary and replace in a first step all the proper utf-8 encodings with html codes.

```
e.g. "\xc2\xa3" to &pound;
```

In a second step I would replace the broken encodings with proper ones.

I got stuck at the first step. Replacing a single character works with replace:

```
string.replace(b'\xc3\x84', b'&Auml;')
```

Taking the code mappings from a table doesn't work. When reading the table the utf-8 codes get escaped (b'\xc3\x84' and I can't find a way to get rid of the double slashes.

I can think of some dirty ways of solving this problem but there should be a clean one, should it?

Comment: In what way is the encoding broken? FWIW, I'd be more inclined to go in the opposite direction: only use named entities for `&quot; &amp; &lt; &gt;` and perhaps `&nbsp;` and use UTF-8 for everything else. Unless you need to support really ancient &/or broken software...

Comment: E.g. I got '\x84' which supposed to be a b'&bdquo;' but if I do a replace(b'\x84', b'&bdquo;') before I replace all the proper utf-8 codes I am destroying proper utf-8 codes like '\xc3\x84' (a.k. '&Auml;') where the \x84 is a part of. So, I think I have to "protect" the utf-8 codes before I can do the replaces.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is either pre filter them

```
iconv -t utf8 -c SRCFILE > NEWFILE
```

Or in python

```
 with open("somefile_with_bad_utf8.txt","rt",encoding="utf-8",errors="ignore") as myfile:
for line in myfile:
  process()
```

I was going to say always use python3 for utf-8 but I see you are already.

Hope that helps....

Comment: Both solutions are eliminating the bad encodings. However, I still need them to replace them by the right characters.